# Electron app sends document to printer, but doesn't print. Debugging printer?

Tags: debugging, printing, electron

We have an application running within Electron which is successfully sending a byte array to the Windows print buffer and printing on all of our printers, except for one: "HP LaserJet Pro M402n". We found an option to print a history and the HP printer is tallying the phantom jobs as printed, but nothing actually was. We're at a bit of a loss on how to debug this, as it seems like an internal printer issue. Does anyone have advice on how to debug something like this? I'm thinking like Fiddler, virtual printer w/ debugger, etc. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If the printer is saying they got printed, then debugging input to the printer isn't going to help (the printer has clearly received the data). What good is intercepting the data stream that the printer already agrees it received going to do?

Comment: I'm assuming you said that due to my "Fiddler" example. That was merely an example of a debugging tool. I'm looking for advice on how to determine the issue the printer is having in printing the document. As I stated in the question, the printer has received enough of the transmission to at least tally it in its internal count of printed documents.